# Accessing the Android camera for a live video

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

```
public SurfaceHolder sh;
public Display(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);

        sh = getHolder();
        sh.addCallback(this);
        sh.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
```

I am trying to access the camera for a live video. But my camera is not getting on. I read that `setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS)` is depreciated for Android 3.0 and above. And it will set automatically when it is needed. But this is not happening.When the application runs I can see a black screen with no image or video. Without using this step how can I run my program? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you like to do,  but if you like to see live preview video you have to configure camera properly and start it. Those demos are known to work on android 4.0 and above ( and on 2.x too):

http://sourceforge.net/p/javaocr/source/ci/5cb9b4176f40ada57296cce79addd205e4c1405c/tree/demos/

Answer (score 0):

you still have to use setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS) to make it work on older platforms.